# What is the purpose of a walled area in the vicinity of Heathrow Airport?

Tags: airline-operations, commercial-operations, airport-design, airport-operations

Looking at a satellite map to the East of Heathrow Airport, there is a small passenger jet parked in a walled off area. Looking at the aerodrome chart the entire area is listed as Bealine Base, which I assume is used for BA operations. What it the purpose of this walled off area?

[image: Walled area in Bealine Base, East of Heathrow]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the steep ramps often erected at large airports?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/what-are-the-steep-ramps-often-erected-at-large-airports)

Comment: There is a similar wall on the corner of Dallas Love Field as seen [in this google street view](https://goo.gl/maps/QZ6gQzpEGVM2).  This wall may actually be a part of some maintenance operation rather than the airport itself, but it's the same principle.

Comment: The suggested-as-duplicated is not the same thing. This is an engine run facility, with 3 walls to contain not just jet blast but also noise. What's in the not-really-a-duplicate question is just a wall to protect an area from jet blast. These engine run facilities have ***far*** more structure than the jet-blast barriers.

Comment: If we told you we'd have to kill you.

Comment: This is a time-out corner for planes which experienced minor incidents on their last flight.

Comment: Here is an example engine test run at full thrust that takes place in this kind of walled off area: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAJNoJvpftY

Comment: It seems that another question does actually provide the answer to this, but in that case the question is asking about a ground run up area that is formed from a loop of taxiway: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/52663/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-loop-in-a-taxiway

Comment: say @Jan thanks for that video - but if it's so dangerous why was there a hand-held camera right there ??  :O

Comment: That's where they reload the airplanes with chemtrails stuff.

Comment: @Fattie it't not so much about being dangerous, it acts more as a sound barrier and to redirect the jet blast away from the airplane or any nearby structures or vehicles

Comment: a few people gave mentioned the sound aspect, @Jan - you know, I really doubt they "stop the sound" much.  Although it might help a bit, sound trivially travels OVER barriers (all that "wave" crap they taught us about in physics, recall! :)  )   I honestly doubt that the primary reason is sound reduction.  I bet the actual reason is indeed safety (stop stuff being thrown around, etc) and any sound reduction is just a bonus.  Anyways.

Comment: Damn - that being said, the link in the answer below specifically shows it as a product primarily focussing on the acoustic aspect!  Heh !   :)  Sometimes, you're wrong ...

Comment: @Fattie, haha yeah I was about to say that, if you look at the link to the IAC website from the answer below they advertise the facility's noise reduction capabilities.

Comment: I left my TOTALLY WRONG comment there, as sometimes you have to man-up to having been TOTALLY WRONG.   (Naturally, usually when I am totally wrong I just delete the post  :-)  )

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It allows them to do a [run-up test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-up_(aviation)) of the engines without blowing debris at other parked aircraft, people, or things on the ground.

[Credit to Ralph J]
The walls have a structure that allows the noise of engine run-ups to be absorbed as well. Engine run-ups, especially multi-engine run ups, can be very loud.

[You can read more about IAC-Acoustics ground run-up enclosures here.](http://www.iac-noisecontrol.com/gres-ground-run-up-enclosures-IAC-Acoustics-Noise-Control-UK.html)

Comment: The walls also are constructed to absorb the considerable ***noise*** that a high-power engine run generates - which is part of the reason that these structures have 3 sides rather than simply 1 wall.

Comment: These are IAC acoustics ground run enclosures; as the name and Ralph J suggest, the primary purpose of their shape is noise reduction.

Comment: If the primary reason for the walls is noise then this answer needs to be modified or another answer given.

Comment: I'll add the extra info from Ralph when I get back to my computer.

Comment: Interestingly, the linked IAC-Acoustics page includes a video with the same run-up enclusure at Heathrow shown in the question - unless there were more than one in that airport. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MRbAaAInMH4

Comment: These structures are super important. My father told me of an incident in Hellinikon airport, where an Olympic Jumbo did a run-up test of the engines, and some policemen that were curious came relatively close (to an agnostic person, they were still far away); the police car rolled over from the blast, killing both guys that day.